# Accessing Companion Class variable from another class

Tags: scala, companion-object

I am really new to scala. I am trying to access a companion class variable from outside the class. How do I do this if at all possible without creating an instance of the class.

In the following example, I can access INTERNAL_COST_REQUESTS from within the YotascaleCostProcessing class

```
package com.yotascale
class YotascaleCostProcessing extends YotascaleActorSystem{

 //companion object
 object YotascaleCostProcessing{
 val INTERNAL_COST_REQUESTS = "internal-cost-requests"
 val INTERNAL_COST_UPDATES = "internal-cost-updates"
}

def setupInfrastructure() = {
    QueueService.createQueue(YotascaleCostProcessing.INTERNAL_COST_REQUESTS)
    QueueService.createQueue(YotascaleCostProcessing.INTERNAL_COST_UPDATES)
  }
}
```

When I do YotascaleCostProcessing.INTERNAL_COST_UPDATES from another class in another package, I get an error "not found: value YotascaleCostProcessing" even though the import for YotascaleCostProcessing is there. The only way this works is when I do this: new YotascaleCostProcessing().YotascaleCostProcessing.INTERNAL_COST_UPDATES

```
package com.yotascale.service.cost.setup;
import com.yotascale.YotascaleCostProcessing
class MetadataNotificationConfiguringActor(message:Message) extends UntypedActor {

def configureBucket() = {
 val realtimeupdates = QueueService.getQueueURL(YotascaleCostProcessing.INTERNAL_COST_REQUESTS)   
}
}
```

Comment: Method is marked as `private`, so you can't do that. You also can't call private, static method from different class in Java/C#.

Comment: Oops let me change that. That;s not what I intended. Copy paste mistake ;). The variable I want to access is not private.

Comment: move your object out of class definition

Comment: Yeah. Just did. Thanks. Can you explain why it wouldn't work when it was within the class definition? Write it as an answer so I can accept it.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just type

```
Foo.counter
```

like

```
import test.Foo
object Test extends App {
  println(Foo.counter)
}
```

and

```
package test
object Foo {
    var counter = 0
}
```

Your problem is that your object definition is inside class definition. Object is just singleton class in Scala, so your definition is like

```
class YotascaleCostProcessing extends YotascaleActorSystem{
  class YotascaleCostProcessing$ {
    val INTERNAL_COST_REQUESTS = "internal-cost-requests"
    val INTERNAL_COST_UPDATES = "internal-cost-updates"
  }
  val YotascaleCostProcessing = new YotascaleCostProcessing$()
}
```

and you can't access to it without instance of YotascaleCostProcessing

Comment: While accessing from another class in some other package, I get an error "not found: value Foo" even though the import for Foo is there. The only way this works is when I do this: new Foo().Foo.counter

Comment: Can you provide minimal example? This call works for me, you may have another problem

Comment: Changed my original question with my actual code. In your example, Foo is an object. In my case, Foo is a class with a companion object Foo contained within.